# Sign up view hierarchy in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

This question is about how people implement SignUp/Registration views in their apps.

1. Do you implement SignUp in LaunchScreen.xib?
2. Do you implement SignUp in some form a modal view controller setup? If so, what is your root view controller?

Are there any basic frameworks one commonly uses to implement sign up views? Any other tips?

Comment: Vote to close because of the way this question is worded it will generate primarily opinion based answers

Comment: Which is exactly what I want?

Comment: Answers should be based on fact not opinion that is way we are given the option to close questions because they are primarily opinion based. Those sort of questions are off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: I am simply asking what people do in their apps — which are also facts. There are hundreds of questions about how stuff is implemented in practice rather than what is 1 + 1. Why is there a big issue here?

Comment: You're asking a question that will generate peoples opinion on best practice and that isn't what SO is for so that is why i have voted to close.

Comment: You answer generate opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the first question based on fact!  No, you should not include any functionality in the xib file you use as your launch screen.  The launch screen is only used to make your app appear to be responsive when it is first launched.  It should not be used as a splash screen or an "about" page!  The launch screen should resemble the very first view of your app as much as possible.

There are so many good answers to the second question that I think you should try it out and see what works best for you.